# mousedown listener doesn't work in Firefox on absolute positioned element

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I ran into a strange problem and I need some help to figure this thing out. I have simple button with one div inside (which has position: absolute), here's the code:

```js
document.querySelector('.mask')
  .addEventListener('mousedown', e => console.log(e.type))
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #1c90f3;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(28, 144, 243, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  click
  <div class="mask"></div>
</button>
```

All I need is to add `mousedown` listener to the `.mask` element. Simple right? 
Well.. turns out Firefox has some problem with that.
 Please check live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fzwbb3dp/ 
When you open console, you can see that in Chrome after you click the button, console logs correct message on `mousedown` event.
 but nothing shows in Firefox console.
 At this point I have completely no idea what is the source of this problem, so I will really appreciate if you can provide some guidance to me how to fix this issue.
 Thank you.

Comment: I would assume it's because Firefox has better rules for buttons and has them how they should be, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402033/missing-click-event-for-span-inside-button-element-on-firefox) for a way to resolve.

Comment: @cookieMan if you will change .mask to button then it will work but then a new issue will be raise that every button will bind with this event.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is that you are using the `<button>` tag in a somewhat unsupported manner, and Firefox is being a stickler about it.

Per MDN, the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element may only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) -- this does *not* include `<div>` elements.  If you change the parent `button` to a `div` it plays nicely (although you'll have to rewrite your CSS).

Comment: Thank you. that's very helpful, although it's weird that other browsers doesn't have problem with that.

Comment: Yeah-- the weird thing about web development is that your code gets deployed on a number of different platforms-- each of which has different implementations of the W3 specs.  Old internet explorer often fails to implement the specs correctly or completely--- by the same token, newer browsers offer varying levels of "forgiveness" when you write code that doesn't completely follow the rules of syntax or structure.  This is one of those cases-- Chrome may let you get by with it, but Mozilla decided they wouldn't put in the work to support improperly formatted HTML.