# Clickable div inside a button doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button, click

I have a expandable section which is a button (this is from a framework that I can not change). And inside this section, I got a clickable div. This is working on Chrome, IE, Safari, but not on Firefox.

```html
<button onclick="alert('expand');" class="button">
   <div onclick="alert('Edit');" class="edit">Edit</div><br/>
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLbkq6uy/1/

I can't fire the click event for the DIV inside this button on Firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253410/link-inside-a-button-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, the `button` itself steals events like  mouse events and click of the child element.  This means things inside buttons cannot be clicked. It is not considered a bug because it works exactly as designed.

[*Source*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003)

Please visit [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402033/missing-click-event-for-span-inside-button-element-on-firefox) also

Based on the above links the solution for Firefox is to change the `button` to some other element like `div` and manage the functionality and design accordingly.