# V-onclick evt.target gets the button inside the span; what should I do?

Tags: html, vue.js, button, vue-component

I have a `button` with a `span` inside it that is set to run a function `v-on:click`.  I try to pick up the `value1` value attached to the `button` (naming convention aside) by catching it as an `evt`.

The problem I'm getting is if I click the side of the button it runs as expected.  But if I click the span inside it, I can't pick up the value1 because the `evt.target` is the span.

I'm converting an existing project to Vue, and this isn't the behavior I expected.  What is the best way to deal with this?

Thanks!

```
<button id="touch-button" class="button float-center" value1="19" v-on:click="emit_values">
  <span>19</span>
</button>
```

```
emit_values(evt){
    $(evt.target).attr("value1")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a generic html/javascript issue.

Solution is here: [Missing click event for <span> inside <button> element on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402033/missing-click-event-for-span-inside-button-element-on-firefox)

I've changed it to target `evt.currentTarger`, then used css to add the `pointer-events: none;` styling to all children of those buttons.